# How to trigger can-deactivate-guard when queryParams change?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular2-routing, candeactivate

I am using the following routing inside app-routing module:

```
path: "overview",
component: OverviewComponent,
children: [
    { path: 'edit', component: DetailComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuardService] }
]
```

My problem is that `canDeactivate` only triggers once, going from `/overview` to `/overview/edit`. I understand that part, because of the child's path inside the routing.

My question is what is a proper solution to make `canDeactivate` trigger whenever the queryParams change inside the `edit` path? For example, changing the url from `/edit?id=1` to `/edit?id=2` should trigger `canDeactivate` aswell.

Is there a simple solution that can be implemented from inside the routing module? 
If not, what do you propose? 
Keep in mind that I am still learning angular.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define when guards and resolvers will be run by setting [RunGuardsAndResolvers](https://angular.io/api/router/RunGuardsAndResolvers) property on router config.

```
path: "overview",
component: OverviewComponent,
children: [
    { path: 'edit',  runGuardsAndResolvers: 'pathParamsOrQueryParamsChange', component: DetailComponent, canDeactivate: [CanDeactivateGuardService] }
]
```

Comment: nice, I was not aware of runGuardsAndResolvers. Thank you!